# How to prepend element into its respective sibling element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list of `div`s, each containing a `div` with class `item` and a `p` with class `text`. I'm trying to move each `p.text` element into its respective `div` sibling using jQuery. Here's what I tried:

```js
$('.text').prependTo('.item');
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p class="text">Sample text.</p>
    <div class="item">
      <p>More text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <p class="text">Sample text.</p>
    <div class="item">
      <p>More text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <p class="text">Sample text.</p>
    <div class="item">
      <p>More text</p>
    </div>
  </div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

It seems to collect all three `p` elements and and put the three into each `div`, creating nine `p` elements, like this:

```
<!-- Undesired result -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"><p class="text">Sample text.</p><p class="text">Sample text.</p><p class="text">Sample text.</p>
          <p>More text</p>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="item"><p class="text">Sample text.</p><p class="text">Sample text.</p><p class="text">Sample text.</p>
        <p>More text</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="item"><p class="text">Sample text.</p><p class="text">Sample text.</p><p class="text">Sample text.</p>
        <p>More text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to use jQuery to just take each `p` element and move it into its respective sibling `div` element, resulting in the following?

```
<!-- Desired result -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
        <p class="text">Sample text.</p>
        <p>More text</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
        <p class="text">Sample text.</p>
        <p>More text</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
        <p class="text">Sample text.</p>
        <p>More text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems to collect all three p elements and and put the three into each div, creating nine p elements.

Yup, that's what that jQuery asks it to do. :-) It says "Find all `.text` elements, and prepend them all to all `.item` elements, making clones as necessary." From the [`prependTo` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/):

> If there is more than one target element, however, cloned copies of the inserted element will be created for each target except the last.

This is the case with all of those sorts of jQuery methods.

Instead, you want a loop:

```
$('.text').each(function() {
  var elm = $(this);
  elm.prependTo(elm.nextAll('.item').first());
});
```

or if you know it'll really be the next sibling:

```
$('.text').each(function() {
  var elm = $(this);
  elm.prependTo(elm.next());
});
```

Example *(I've added a border to the `.item` elements so you can see the text moves into them)*:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#legend").text("AFTER");
  $('.text').each(function() {
    var elm = $(this);
    elm.prependTo(elm.nextAll('.item').first());
  });
}, 600);
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="legend">BEFORE</div>
<div class="container">
  <p class="text">Sample text.</p>
  <div class="item">
    <p>More text</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p class="text">Sample text.</p>
  <div class="item">
    <p>More text</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p class="text">Sample text.</p>
  <div class="item">
    <p>More text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```